# regex: удалить повторяющиеся фразы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Требуется удалить лишние дубликаты, если они есть. Пример ниже (удалить дубликаты "г. Воронеж") не работает.

```
gsub(pattern = "(г\\.\\s\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b,)\\1{2,}",replacement = "\\1",x="г. Воронеж, г. Воронеж, г. Воронеж, ул. Ленинский пр-т,174",ignore.case = T)
```

Comment: Требуется удалить только те дубликаты, которые следуют друг за другом?

Comment: Да, причем есть и адреса, где дубликатов нет (один город без повторений)

Comment: Там, где нет дубликатов, и удалять не надо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В оригинальном регулярном выражении обратная ссылка на значение первой захватывающей группы содержит `г. Воронеж,`, поэтому сразу после `г. Воронеж,` должен следовать ещё один `г. Воронеж,`, но после запятой следует пробел.

Используйте

```
p <- "(г\\.\\s*[[:alpha:]]+)(?:,\\s*\\1)+"
x <- "г. Воронеж, г. Воронеж, г. Воронеж, ул. Ленинский пр-т,174"
gsub(p,"\\1", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

См. [R-демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/IaNebl)

**Описание**:

- `(г\.\s*[[:alpha:]]+)` - Захватывающая группа №1:

  - `г\.` - `г.`
  - `\s*`  - 0+ пробелов
  - `[[:alpha:]]+` - 1+ букв
- `(?:,\\s*\\1+)+` - 1+ повторов следующих шаблонов:

  - `,\\s*` - запятая + ноль и более пробелов
  - `\\1` - значение в первой захватывающей группе.

Comment: можете дать чуть больше деталей по "?:" - что это?

Comment: Это *не*захватывающая группа, которая не создаёт обратных ссылок (т.е. не хранит часть полученного совпадения в буфере памяти, как это делает захватывающая группа). Служит только для группирования шаблонов.

Comment: Ваш ответ помог, спасибо. Решил дополнить свой вариант пробелом в конце и он то же заработал. `pattern = "(*г\\.\\s\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b,\\s)\\1{2,}"`